# Using array as a wherekey when searching objects in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, search, parse-platform, tags

I am trying to implement a search bar that searches tags related to a photo. I am using Parse to retrieve an image, and tags are stored with the image in the same object as arrays. However, I could not use the following code to search for objects. In the following code, "tagArray" represents the column in Parse where tags are stored. Thank you in advance!

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Tops")

    query.whereKey("tagArray", containsString: searchTextF.text)

    // Fetch data from the parse platform
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            println("success")

        } else {
            println("error")
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please post more of your code. Preferably everything relating to your query that you are performing. What are you calling after `query.whereKey("tagArray", containsString: searchTextBar.text)`?

Comment: Thank you! And are you getting a `success` printed out in the console?

Comment: Actually, when I try to do this, this error occurs. "Error Domain=Parse Code=102 "$regex only works on string fields""

Comment: Hmmm, this may be because `searchTextF.text` is optional and can be nil. For now, try: `query.whereKey("tagArray", containsString: searchTextF.text as! String)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I get the same error again...

Comment: I just tried your code replacing the query names with one of my classes in Parse and everything worked. Your "tagArray" column is a column of `String`s, correct?

Comment: Never mind. I was able to solve the issue! I just had to replace "containsString" with "equalTo". Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad you found the solution!